# How to check a checkbox querying MySQL which record is boolean

Tags: jquery, mysql, checkbox

I have the following MySQL table:

```
|  id   |    Name    |  Windows | Linux |
-----------------------------------------
|   1   |  Photoshop |     1    |   0   |
-----------------------------------------
|   2   |  Gimp      |     0    |   1   |
```

By clicking the above names as follows:

```
<a class="editlink" id="<?php echo $review['id']; ?>" href="#"><?php echo  $review['title']; ?></a>
```

I'm able to populate a form with the following JQuery code:

```
$(".editlink").click(function() {
    $.get("lists.php", {param2: $(this).attr('id')}, 
    function(data) {
        jsonOBJ = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                for (var key in jsonOBJ) {
                     $(":input[name='" + key + "']").val(jsonOBJ[key]);
                }
        }   
);    
    return false;
});
```

And this is the form:

```
<form method ="post" action="review.php">   
    <input class="edit_title" type="text" size="51" value="" name="title"/><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="windows"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="linux"/>
</form>
```

The LIST.PHP file is the following:

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reviews JOIN filters ON reviews.id = filters.id WHERE reviews.id = ".$_GET['param2']." ");    
    while($review = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
        $arr = array('id_field' => $review['id'],
                     'title' => $review['name'],
                     'windows' => $review['Windows'],
                     'linux' => $review['Linux']
        );
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

But I don't know how to check or uncheck the checkboxes accordingly to the boolean value (0 or 1) saved into the database.
For example, if JSON returns "windows":"1", how do I 'convert' this '1' into 'checked'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

I would amend your PHP to return a boolean value for the checkbox fields like this:

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reviews JOIN filters ON reviews.id = filters.id WHERE reviews.id = ".$_GET['param2']." ");    
    while($review = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
        $arr = array('id_field' => $review['id'],
                     'title' => $review['name'],
                     'windows' => $review['Windows'] == "1",
                     'linux' => $review['Linux'] == "1"
        );
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

Then you can simply set the returned value as the `checked` attribute on the radio button:

```
$(".editlink").click(function() {
    $.get(
        "lists.php", 
        { param2: $(this).attr('id') }, 
        function(data) {
            jsonOBJ = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            for (var key in jsonOBJ) {
                $(":input[name='" + key + "']").attr("checked", jsonOBJ[key]);
            }
        }   
    );    
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you Rory. The code return - for example - "windows":"1". What should I do if I have a FOR LOOP as you can see in my above JQuery code? I simply add your line inside the FOR LOOP but it did not work.

Comment: Sorry Rory. Doesn't work. The PHP part you suggested does work. It returns "windows":true. But the JQuery part does nothing. By the way, I need the .val(jsonOBJ[key]) part too not only the .attr part because I need the values of the record too. Can you help me?

Comment: Maybe I have to specify that checkboxes are inside a table? Maybe the problem is that the selector is not correct?

Comment: Ok, fixed. Problem was incompatibility with [Uniform](http://uniformjs.com/) jQuery plug-in